# Tried everything I know but still get "unexpected end of input"

Tags: angularjs

I am following a tutorial for building a CRUD application using PHP and mySQL. When I enter the code below into my angular-script.js file the last line (a curly brace) gets flagged as containing an error. (I'm using Dreamweaver CS6 as my code editor). When I run the file in the browser the console throws an error that says "unexpected end of input" and references the line that holds the curly brace that I mentioned above. Can someone tell me where my code goes wrong below? I've tried closing what I think needs to be closed, counted brackets, braces, and parentheses but nothing seems to work. Thank you.

```
// Application module
var crudApp = angular.module('crudApp',[]);
crudApp.controller("DbController",['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){

// Function to get employee details from the database
getInfo();
function getInfo(){
// Sending request to EmpDetails.php files
$http.post('databaseFiles/empDetails.php').success(function(data){
// Stored the returned data into scope
$scope.details = data;
});
}
```

Comment: Count +1 for each `{` then -1 for each `}`. If you don't end up with zero, you have unbalanced blocks. By my count, you end up with 1 + 1 + 1 - 1 - 1 = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be a way easier with good indent. Try this:

```
// Application module
var crudApp = angular.module('crudApp',[]);

crudApp.controller("DbController",['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){

  function getInfo(){

    // Sending request to EmpDetails.php files
    $http.post('databaseFiles/empDetails.php').success(function(data){
      // Stored the returned data into scope
      $scope.details = data;
    });
  }

  // Function to get employee details from the database
  getInfo();
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing }]) at the end of the file